# How to disable android application automatic restart after a crash (Android 2.2)

Tags: android

Is there a way to disable android application automatic restart after a crash (Android 2.2)? Application crashes and after it android restarts application. It seems that android tries to restore activity back stack and it causes issues because all data which was received from the server on login is gone.

UPDATE: my application starts with login screen on which it loads some data from server and in case of restart after crash no login is done

I see that there is simmilar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245550/android-app-restarts-automatically-after-a-crash)  but without solution

Comment: Id like to know the answer to this question too...

Comment: I too have been searching for an answer to this.  We have startup code in our Launch Activity, and when the auto-restart takes place, it seems to go directly to crashed Activity without going through the Launcher.  Startup code is thus not called, and we crash again...and again...and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It has a simple solution after crashing if your activity is
  restarting then check at start point that this activity has all
  required data of login or not if it has not all the data then
  redirect it to login activity.

Comment: This is what we did at that time :) so +1